# Accessing Database created in XAMPP while working in Laravel 5 homestead

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, laravel-5, homestead

I'm starting a large project in Laravel 5. In the past I used XAMPP for all local work. Now we're going to work in Homestead. I got Homestead set up and running and I booted up a Laravel 5 project in it. works fine.

Because of various reasons we do NOT want to use Laravel migrations but are using MYSQL workbench in combo with XAMPP-PHPMyAdmin for work on the mysql database. My question is: how can I access this mysql database from within the Homestead VM?

I tried all kinds of settings in the app/Config/database.php. but none work.

I looked around for related questions here, but none seem to answer the base of my question: is it even possible to access a remote database (or one on my host machine) from within homestead?

I read somewhere that I can create migrations from an SQL dump to duplicate the DB in homestead using a package (https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator). using this as a workaround, I could connect my Laravel app to my DB I have set up in XAMPP, generate the migrations, then connect back to the Homestead DB and finally run the migrations. I think this could work but I would prefer direct connection. any suggestions on how to connect to a database outside the Homestead VM would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

<1>Open .env  (can be found in root of laravel)

<2>Change DB_HOST to your LAN IP address(something like 198.168.0.11)

DB_HOST=LAN_IP

<3>Now go to phpmyadmin and in privileges tab
  Add new user and fill login info

Select host as any_host(or fill host with your PC name)

Answer (score 1):

I am also relatively new to Laravel and Homestead too but have had some luck with it.

First I'm not sure it's such a great idea not to use the MySQL instance inside Homestead but if you have your reasons I'll take you at your word. That said from your "Homestead" directory you can "vagrant ssh" into your Homestead VM.

Here you can mysql -u homestead -psecret dbname into your database and configure it at will just as you would your XAMPP instance. If you are using Laravel models as long as they match the database you'll be fine.

To your point of connecting to another database from within the VM have you tried to connect to that outside database from the command line? As long as your XAMPP MySQL instance is configured to receive remote connections and you have a user properly configured you should be able to test from the command line from within the Vagrant VM. See below where 192.168.1.196 is the IP address of the box/VM containing the MySQL instance to which you want to connect. I'm not running XAMPP but I was able to make a connection from within Vagrant Homestead out of the VM to another MySQL instance running on my local machine by providing my local network address. "127.0.0.1" won't work obviously because the Vagrant VM will perceive that as itself.

```
mysql -u user -ppassword dbname -h 192.168.1.196
```

Hope this helps.